# Why pipenv is not using its wheel cache?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, pipenv

Whenever I install a new package (without using the `--skip-lock` option), pipenv downloads and (in case of non-binary dependencies) compiles all the packages from the scratch, even though the wheels are already cached in `~/.cache/pipenv`. This makes the whole development process slow, since I have a lot of packages that need to be compiled from the source. 
Currently I download and compile my packages using pip, use `pypi-server` to run a local package server, and point my pipenv to it (using [[source]]). But I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? I am using the latest version of `pipenv` and it does use the cache.